# Google Maps iOS, pathFromEncodedPath

Tags: objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

Wondering if I've come across a bug or if I'm using the `pathFromEncodedPath` incorrect?

```
GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath pathFromEncodedPath:@"o|}bF~bsgV_pR??~`f@~oR?"];
GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
rectangle.map = mapView_;
```

The above code is giving me the exception:

```
+[GMSMutablePath count]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2839a8
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[GMSMutablePath count]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2839a8'
```

I've confirmed using the [Interactive Polyline Encoder Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility) that my encoded polyline is valid.

Looking to see if anyone has a suggestion or if they've come across this issue, too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the current version 1.3, and it will be fixed in the next release.

The work around for now is to create a GMSPath and then convert that to a GMSMutablePath.